# How Do I Grep All Files In A Non-Project Directory With Projectile?

Tags: emacs, clojure

My root project folder is not a project in Projectile, but I often want to search all my projects for a string to see where I've used or defined a given function before. How do I search the contents of all my projects recursively in Emacs? I realize Projectile may not be the best approach, and I'm also curious about others. However, as things stand, Projectile prompts me for a specific project, as opposed to a parent parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the builtin <kbd>M-x</kbd>`rgrep` function to recursively search for a regex in your directory tree.

Comment: And so does this!

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use the silver searcher (ag), which has wrapper packages in Emacs, e. g. `helm-ag`.